# How to performantly get every (unordered) pair of different collection elements if random access is not available

Tags: c#, iteration, ienumerator

Example: I have the collection `{1, 2, 3, 4}`.
I want to get all (unordered) pairs of different elements, which are:
`{1,2}`, `{1,3}`, `{1,4}`, `{2,3}`, `{2,4}`, `{3,4}`.

If I have an `IList`, I can do it like this:

```
IList<MyType> list = ... // fill the list elements

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
    for (int j = i+1; j < list.Count; j++)
        {
            ... // now we have the pair of list[i] and list[j]
        }
```

For a `LinkedList` I also know how to do it; it is almost the same except that instead of indexes `i` and `j`, we have two `LinkedListNode`s `fst` and `snd`. Whenever we call `fst.Next`, we will then set `snd = fst.Next`.

For a list of `n` elements, the above approach takes `(n-1)*n/2` iteration steps. (For `i = 0` we have `j = 1 ... n-1`, so `n-1` steps. For `i = 1` we have `j = 2 ... n-1`, so `n-2` steps. And so on. This sums up to `(n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 3 + 2 + 1 = (n-1)*n/2` steps.)

Is there a way to do it with any `ICollection`? I thought an `IEnumerator` could do the trick, but it seems there is no way to tell an `IEnumerator` "Move to that reference!" like I can do with `LinkedListNode`s.

EDIT:

I am NOT looking for this solution:

```
foreach (MyType a in list)
    foreach (MyType b in list)
    {
        if (a == b)
            continue;

        ... // now we have the pair of a and b
    }
```

For a collection of `n` elements, this approach takes `n^2` iteration steps which is a bit more than double than the above approach, so it is clearly not as performant.

EDIT:

Turning the collection into a `List` beforehand seems to be the easiest way, and the performance penalty is negligible for large `n`, because it only adds `n` steps to the whole interation (the new list must be filled by the `n` elements). So I'll just stick with it.

Comment: You can create custom classes that inherit IEnumerable or IEnumerator.  Enumerable if for loops and Enumerator is foreach loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerable` is a forward-only iterator; `ICollection` does not have indexed access. What you could do is get the enumerable into a buffer during the first iteration, and afterwards use the nested `for` loops.

```
var enumerable = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);

var buffer = new List<int>();

using (var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
{
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        buffer.Add(enumerator.Current);
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var current = enumerator.Current;
            buffer.Add(current);

            Handle(buffer[0], current);
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 1; i < buffer.Count - 1; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < buffer.Count; j++)
        Handle(buffer[i], buffer[j]);
```

Alternatively, if you don't care about going through the items one more time, you could just use `enumerable.ToArray()` and then use the nested `for` on that array.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Based on the discussion in comments and the edited question it seems that copying the enumerable in a list is the best course of action.

Old answer:

It seems to me that you need to put the items into some kind of hashtable data structure.

Here is a LINQ based solution that uses GroupBy

```
var items = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 2, 3 };

var groupedItems = from i in items
                   group i by i into g
                   select g;

foreach (var group in groupedItems)
{
    //group.Key stores the key of the grouping
    foreach (var item in group) //group contains items with the same key
    {
        //Do something
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Here each group contains items with the same key (in this example because the item is an int the item is the key but you can group by whatever expression you want)

Alternatively you can group stuff on your own using a dictionary

```
var items = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 2, 3 };
var itemsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

foreach (int i in items)
{
    List<string> repeatedValues;
    if(itemsDictionary.TryGetValue(i, out repeatedValues))
    {
        repeatedValues.Add(i.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        itemsDictionary.Add(i, new List<string> { i.ToString() });
    }
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<string>> kvp in itemsDictionary)
{
    //do whatever is needed kvp.Value

}
```

In this example I've used a string to emulate a key of int and a value of different type. I think both these solutions are NlogN

Alternatively - sort the collection in a list - all equal elements will be placed one after another. This will be NlogN solution.

Comment: I do not actually want to compare values; CompareTo was just an intuitive example of what someone could want to do with every pair fo elements of a collection. I updated my question to make clearer what I want.

Comment: You want to compare each and every value to every other value? If this is the case I don't think you can do any better than O^2

Comment: No, it will certainly not be better than O(n^2). But there is a difference between `n^2` comparisons as in the `foreach a, foreach b` case, and `(n-1)*n/2` comparisons as in the `for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++), for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)` case. Factor `2` is nothing I would disregard.

Comment: I see. Why not just put them into a list before you start?

Comment: Seems the easiest way to me, and I will probably stick with it (would be `n` steps for filling the list plus `(n-1)*n/2` steps for iterating, which is still around half of the steps of the `foreach a, foreach b` approach) in the meantime.

Comment: I guess the only way to achieve absolutely maximum performance is to use the first inner iteration to fill the list. However it seems to be an overkill for a small improvement and there is still the need for GC of the list object.