# How to get every unordered pair of elements, without repetition from two lists lazyly?

Tags: java, iterator, java-stream, lazy-evaluation, iterable

This is the same question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674207/how-to-performantly-get-every-unordered-pair-of-different-collection-elements) but in Java, since in C# yield would fix my problem.

Example: if have [1,2] [5,6]. I would like to get [1,5] [1,6] [2,5] [2,6]

But if I have only one list [1,2,3] the result would be [1,2] [1,3] [2,3]

This is what I have:

```
public static <T,K> Collection<Entry<T,K>> Pairs (List<T> l1, List<K> l2)
{
    Collection<Entry<T,K>> result = new LinkedList<>();

    for(int i =0;i<l1.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=(l1==l2?i+1:0);j<l2.size();j++)
        {
            result.add(new Entry<>(l1.get(i),l2.get(j)));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I just want to make the method lazy. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not easy to create a lazy `Collection`. Would `Iterable` or `Iterator` suffice?

Comment: @shmosel That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very complicated to create a lazy `Collection` that would support `add()`, `remove()` etc. But you can easily return an `Iterator` (which is inherently lazy) using streams:

```
public static <T, K> Iterator<Entry<T, K>> pairs(List<T> l1, List<K> l2) {
    return IntStream.range(0, l1.size())
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(l1 == l2 ? i + 1 : 0, l2.size())
                    .mapToObj(j -> new Entry<>(l1.get(i), l2.get(j))))
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .iterator();
}
```

The above can easily be converted to an `Iterable` if so desired:

```
Iterable<Entry<T, K>> iterable = () -> pairs(l1, l2);
```

Comment: Very nice answer, +1 for using `flatMap(Function.identity())`. Leads to a type mismatch issue with Eclipse compiler but is easily fixed by adding `<Entry<T, K>>` just before the inner `mapToObj` and after the dot.

Comment: @MarkusBenko Worked for me in Eclipse with `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`.

Comment: Strange. Copied and pasted your code, added a simple Entry implementation with two-args constructor and Eclipse 4.4.2 and throws the following error here: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterator<Object> to Iterator<Entry<T,K>>`.

Comment: @MarkusBenko I'm using 4.6.2. It's probably an old bug.

Answer (score 0):

The iterator approach proposed by @shmosel is a good idea, here is my take:

For this to work for a single list, the incoming lists would have to be equal. For example `1,2,3` and `1,2,3` will produce :

> 1=2  1=3  2=3

```
public static Iterator<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>> test(List<Integer> left, List<Integer> right) {

    return IntStream.range(0, left.size()).boxed().flatMap(i -> left.equals(right)
            ? left.stream().skip(i + 1).map(j -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(left.get(i), j))
            : right.stream().map(j -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(left.get(i), j)))
            .iterator();
}
```